# How to find current Solr version from file

Tags: solr, version

How to find the current version of Solr if the ip:8983/solr/admin is unreachable (the solr itself is running and responds)? Is it possible to read the current version from one of the files in the file system, or to build a custom php query to get this value? (if the query is needed please be kind to provide an example or reference, Thanks)

Comment: Isn't the version is the name of the war file?

Answer (score 3):

In my Solr 1.4.1 setup the war file was only solr.war, but I have found the version in CHANGES.txt

Answer (score 2):

Lib name from solr-webapp/WEB-INF may be helpful for You: **solr-core-4.4.0.jar**

Answer (score 0):

How are you deploying your solr war file. If you are using the default example folder then u can see one of the files to check the version. Or in ur application is the client need the version of solr? But what is the use of that?

Answer (score 0):

In version 7.7.1 there is a file LUCENE_CHANGES.txt

---

Lucene Change Log

For more information on past and future Lucene versions, please see:
http://s.apache.org/luceneversions

======================= Lucene 7.7.1 =======================
(No Changes)

======================= Lucene 7.7.0 =======================

Changes in Runtime Behavior

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to go to the SOLR install location and execute:

```
./solr version
```

Example:

```
[root@node bin]# pwd
/usr/lib/ambari-infra-solr/bin
[root@node bin]# ./solr version
7.7.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses command:

```
cd /opt/solr/bin/
./solr version
```